# Codename One - Play a sound

Tags: codenameone

The following code works fine in the Simulator, I hear the audio:

```
    try {
        Media m = MediaManager.createMedia((Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/notification_sound_bell.mp3")), "audio/mpeg");
        m.play();
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
    }
```

But it doesn't work at all on real Android devices. What's wrong?
On the generated apk, the "notification_sound_bell.mp3" file is placed in /res/raw folder.

On an Android 4.x device I get:

> [EDT] 0:0:0,118 - Codename One revisions: 3b20edadec808867afc2b19774268b66890616ad
>
> [EDT] 0:0:0,129 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createMedia(AndroidImplementation.java:2802)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:2998)  at
>   com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:125)
>     at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:94)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:66)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplicationStub.run(MyApplicationStub.java:140)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1116)   at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:911)    at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) [EDT] 0:0:0,214 - Exception
>   in Alert every five minutes version 1.0 [EDT] 0:0:0,215 - OS and [EDT]
>   0:0:0,215 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException [EDT] 0:0:0,216 -
>   Current Form null [EDT] 0:0:0,217 - Exception:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException - null java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createMedia(AndroidImplementation.java:2802)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:2998)  at
>   com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:125)
>     at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:94)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:66)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplicationStub.run(MyApplicationStub.java:140)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1116)   at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:911)    at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

On an Android 7.x device I get:

> [EDT] 0:0:20,186 - Codename One revisions:
>   3b20edadec808867afc2b19774268b66890616ad
>
> [EDT] 0:0:20,191 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt
>   to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int,
>   int)' on a null object reference java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[],
>   int, int)' on a null object reference     at
>   com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createMedia(AndroidImplementation.java:2802)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:2998)  at
>   com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:125)
>     at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:94)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:66)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplicationStub.run(MyApplicationStub.java:140)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1116)   at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:911)    at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) [EDT] 0:0:20,198 - Exception
>   in Alert every five minutes version 1.0 [EDT] 0:0:20,199 - OS and
>   [EDT] 0:0:20,201 - Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)'
>   on a null object reference [EDT] 0:0:20,202 - Current Form null [EDT]
>   0:0:20,204 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)'
>   on a null object reference java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'int java.io.InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)'
>   on a null object reference    at
>   com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.createMedia(AndroidImplementation.java:2802)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.createMedia(Display.java:2998)  at
>   com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:125)
>     at com.codename1.media.MediaManager.createMedia(MediaManager.java:94)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:66)
>     at
>   it.galgani.app.fiveMinutesAlert.MyApplicationStub.run(MyApplicationStub.java:140)
>     at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1116)   at
>   com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:911)    at
>   com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)    at
>   com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)

Comment: I also tried without success: `Media m = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia("file:///notification_sound_bell.mp3"); m.play();` It gives me "file:///notification_sound_bell.mp3 error java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed."

Comment: Is `notification_sou‌​nd_bell.mp3` in the root of your `src` folder in the project?

Comment: Yes, it is in `<project dir>/src/notification_sound_bell.mp3`

Comment: Notice that the resource isn't a file so the background media call you made won't work. I just noticed you mentioned that the mp3 is placed in the raw folder which is wrong. It should be in the assets folder. Try giving the file a different name. This might be a problem in the build server logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems our system has a special treatment to the `notification_sound` prefix in a file name on Android for usage with background notification sounds on Android. Just rename the file to something else and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you, renaming from `notification_sound_bell.mp3` to `bell.mp3` solved this issue. I suggest you to add a warning in the log of the Simulator when the user is using a reserved prefix in a file name to prevent issues like this.

Comment: I had no idea this was a reserved prefix myself. Please file an issue we'll try to make sure this is clarified